# JVM 104 : Stack OverFlow Error in Blackberry Simulator

Tags: android, blackberry, stack-overflow

I am getting this error in my program after adding few label and editfield, then passing the saved value to the other class.

It gave me StackOverFlow error when I pressed on the particular button, yet the class did not implements any Hashtable elements.

> LongHashtable.get(long) line: 454

And this is the class I mentioned about.

```
public final class RSSMainScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener{

RSSFeedList rfl = new RSSFeedList ();

String rssUrl1 = "http://kompas.feedsportal.com/c/33612/f/589626/index.rss";
String rssUrl2 = "http://feeds.gawker.com/lifehacker/full";
String rssUrl3 = rfl.x ;

ButtonField viewRSSButton = new ButtonField("Refresh");
ButtonField editRSSButton = new ButtonField("Settings");

DefaultHandler dh = new DefaultHandler();

public RSSMainScreen()
{       

    // Set the displayed title of the screen       
    HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);

    setTitle("");

    viewRSSButton.setChangeListener(this);
    editRSSButton.setChangeListener(this);

    String[][] urlData1 = dh.getURLFromRSS(rssUrl1);
    String[][] urlData2 = dh.getURLFromRSS(rssUrl2);
    String[][] urlData3 = dh.getURLFromRSS(rssUrl3);


    add(new LabelField("KOMPAS"));
    add(new SeparatorField());

    for (int i = 0; i < urlData1.length; i++) 
    {
        String title = urlData1[0][i];
        String url = urlData1[1][i];
        add(new LinkLabel(title, url));
        add(new SeparatorField());
    }

    add(new LabelField("LIFEHACKER"));
    add(new SeparatorField());

    for (int i = 0; i < urlData2.length; i++) 
    {
        String title = urlData2[0][i];
        String url = urlData2[1][i];
        add(new LinkLabel(title, url));
        add(new SeparatorField());
    }

    add(new LabelField("CUSTOM"));
    add(new SeparatorField());

    for (int i = 0; i < urlData3.length; i++) 
    {
        String title = urlData3[0][i];
        String url = urlData3[1][i];
        add(new LinkLabel(title, url));
        add(new SeparatorField());
    }

    hfm.add(viewRSSButton);
    hfm.add(editRSSButton);

    this.add(hfm);
}
```

This it the class from where the String value will be passed.

May I know how to solve this issue?

```
public class RSSFeedList extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {
RSSMainScreen rms = new RSSMainScreen();

ButtonField backButton = new ButtonField("Cancel and Back");
ButtonField saveButton = new ButtonField("Save");
BasicEditField thirdURL = new BasicEditField();

String x  = "";

protected RSSFeedList()
{
    HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);

    backButton.setChangeListener(this);
    saveButton.setChangeListener(this);

    LabelField firstURLLabel = new LabelField("First RSS");
    LabelField firstURL = new LabelField(rms.rssUrl1);

    LabelField secondURLLabel = new LabelField("Second RSS");
    LabelField secondURL = new LabelField(rms.rssUrl2);

    LabelField thirdURLLabel = new LabelField("Third RSS (Editable)");

    hfm.add(firstURLLabel);
    hfm.add(new SeparatorField());
    hfm.add(firstURL);
    hfm.add(new SeparatorField());
    hfm.add(secondURLLabel);
    hfm.add(new SeparatorField());
    hfm.add(secondURL);
    hfm.add(new SeparatorField());
    hfm.add(thirdURLLabel);
    hfm.add(new SeparatorField());
    hfm.add(thirdURL);
    hfm.add(new SeparatorField());

    hfm.add(backButton);
    hfm.add(saveButton);

    this.add(hfm);
}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
{
    if(field == backButton)
    {
        //screen = new RSSMainScreen();
    }
    else if(field == saveButton)
    {
        x = thirdURL.getText().toString();
        //screen = new RSSMainScreen();
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new RSSMainScreen());
    }

}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Some code would help us to help you

Comment: Can you post the entire code in the class. Stack Over Flow Error is caused if you are doing repeated method calls and the stack becomes full.

Comment: Your title shook my soul. Please edit the title I was worried

Comment: The code is there now, sorry for the delay.

Comment: I'm not sure which button is the particular one which causing the exception, but clicking on the save button will surely cause IllegalArgumentException. Check this, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html#popScreen%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen%29.

Comment: @Rupak , why is that so? Does it mean that I need to apply the paint and layout methods for the target class?

Comment: IllegalArgumentException will be thrown because you are trying to pop a screen instance from the display stack which was never pushed into that. If you need to pop an instance of RSSMainScreen (which may be pushed earlier) you have to use the reference of that object, don't use `new` there. Also add try-catch block around pop code block.

Comment: I changed the popScreen into pushScreen yet it gave me StackOverflow error now, I wonder why?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you run out of memory/stack resources on your device at the runtime.

When you press a button you compose (a quite complex) screen and push it on the screen stack.
And when a button on the new screen is pressed, then you produce new object and push this new screen to the stack.

This is not a good approach at all. Instead of that consider having one screen and update its content via change event. Do not produce new screens, update content of the existing one.